# Consider $f: S^1 \to$ Figure Eight. $f$ is an immersion, but how?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am reading Guillemin and Pollack.

The definition of an immersion they give is:

> $f: X \to Y$ is an immersion at $x \in X$ if $df_x : T_x(X) \to T_y(Y)$ is injective. If $f$ is an immersion $\forall x \in X$, then we say that $f$ is an immersion.

So apparently the map from the circle to the figure 8 is an immersion, as they state on the next page. But what about the critical point in the mapping $f$? There is no tangent space defined here, correct? So then how could $f$ possibly be an immersion?

Also, is there a simple example of something that isn't an immersion that will help me remember this definition?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider the figure eight as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $f \colon S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is an immersion [if $f$ is chosen correctly] with image "$8$".

Comment: The map is from $S^1 \to \Bbb R^2$. You need to check (after suitably defining a parametrization), that the derivative $df_x : T_xS^1 \to T_{f(x)}\Bbb R^2$ is injective at all $x$ in $S^1$.

Comment: Which point do you think is critical?

Answer (score 1):

you can consider the derivative map of $f$ such a way that map a tangent vector on $S^{1}$ to a tangent vector on eight figure. Hence each tangent vector maps to only one tangent vector on eight figure. So $df_{x}$ is one-to-one.